# Is it good idea to disable eslint prop validation in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Every time when I am writing react code Property validation error popups up. Initially, I resolve these all by validating each props passed to a component by PropTypes library. But recently I found this **/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */** snippet to disable props validation. Is this a good practice? Does it affect my performance of my application?

Comment: Eslint has nothing to do with your app performance as its a static syntax analyzer, and to begin with, linting rules are opinionated

Comment: If you asking about `prop-types` package performance, you can turn it off in production (I'm sure its turned off by default), anyway you should measure and define whats "good performance" is, we can't guess that